# Не выводятся связанные поля django rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Осваиваю Django и DRF. Расширил модель пользователя через создание UserModel и связывания с базовой моделью через 
`user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usermodel")`

Столкнулся с проблемой: нужно по запросу получить текущего пользователя и все данные. На данный момент получается вывести или поля стандартной модели User, или новой UserModel, но никак не все вместе.

serialisers.py:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('user', 'adress', 'department', 'phoneNumbers')
```

views.py:

```
class CurrentUserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
queryset = User.objects.all().select_related('usermodel')
permission_classes = [IsOwnerProfileOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated]

def get(self, request):
    serializer = UserProfileSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Поля adress, department и phoneNumbers приходят, а поля из User - нет

Comment: Нужно было расширять не второй моделью, а наследованием первой и заменой AUTH_USER_MODEL в настройках. https://habr.com/ru/post/313764/

Comment: Я по этой статье и смотрел. Но не хватает опыта, чтобы выбрать оптимальный способ расширения) Проще будет добить текущий вариант или создать свою модель с наследованием от AbstractUser? Ну и что универсальнее по итоге

Comment: Оба варианта имеют место быть, зависит от того как проектируется БД например вариант с OneToOne будет проще расширять на продакшене, когда БД уже нельзя будет удалить и пересоздать заново.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в UserProfileSerializer добавить depth=1 в класс Meta

```
`class Meta:
    model = UserModel
    fields = ('user', 'adress', 'department', 'phoneNumbers')
    depth = 1`
```

Или можешь изменить в UserProfileSerializer поле user, чтобы его обрабатывал UserSerializer:

`user = UserSerializer(many=False)`

Comment: Оба варианта пробовал, почему-то не было эффекта. Решил сделать через наследование от AbstractUser, на данный момент все ок)